# generate pdf file from jasper report with servlet java code

Tags: servlets, report

I have a jasper report, I put it in the same package as servlets, I need to generate pdf file from it, but the code doesn't work and doesn't gives any error

```
public void print(String numBac , HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {          
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader
                .load("fiche.jrxml");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM etudiant "
                + "INNER JOIN filiere ON etudiant.code_f=filiere.code_f "
                + "INNER JOIN lieu_nais ON etudiant.code_lieu=lieu_nais.code_lieu "
                + "INNER JOIN montant ON etudiant.code_m=montant.code_m WHERE bac='"
                + numBac + "'";
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(sql);
        jasperDesign.setQuery(newQuery);
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager
                .compileReport(jasperDesign);
        //JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, cnx);
        //JasperViewer.viewReport(print);

        byte[] byteStream;
        byteStream = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(report, null, cnx);
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setHeader("Content-Sisposition", "inline,filename="+DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME);
        response.setContentType(FILE_TYPE);
        response.setContentLength(byteStream.length);
        outStream.write(byteStream, 0, byteStream.length);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

even if I want to generate jasper preview it doesn't shown up (code in comment)

Comment: i think .jrxml is a resource file so have you tried it by deploying it in a new source folder ?

Comment: I saw some tutorials where they put it like this with servlets cause servlets are source files

Answer (score 5):

What is baos for? Do you have to flush/close sos?
 **You can use bellow code. Here is complete Example using java servlet**

1. Please download bellow jar file..

   1. jasperreports-5.0.1.jar
   2. commons-logging-1.1.2.jar
   3. commons-digester-2.1.jar
   4. commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar
   5. commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
   6. groovy-all-2.1.3.jar
   7. com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar
   8. your database library

**You can use like**

```
 @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     try {
        String path = "D:\\Software\\iReport-5.0.0-windows-installer\\u\\report4.jrxml";
        JasperReport jasReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);
        System.out.println("Jasper Report : " + jasReport);
        //Database connection 
        Connection con = /*Database Connection*/;
        System.out.println(con);

          //If You have any Paramert use bellow like
          Map paramMap = new HashMap();
         paramMap.put("id", request.getParameter("id"));

         //If You don't have parameter pass null instead of paramMap
        JasperPrint jasPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasReport, paramMap, con);
        System.out.println("Jasper Print : " + jasPrint);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasPrint, sos);

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a spelling error here:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Sisposition", "inline,filename="+DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME);
```

It should say "Disposition" instead of "Sisposition":

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline,filename="+DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME);
```

Also, try using "attachment" instead of "inline":

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment,filename="+DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME);
```

And flush and close the outStream:

```
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Hope it helps!